# Windows Service State Running but not working

Tags: c#, windows-services

After couple days (like 3 days or so) my windows service just stops executing the system.timer events don't fire anymore but the service shows as running. Also my log files don't even get created so no errors are thrown and logged. I have try catches on the highest level as well as on the second highest level and also in the constructor, OnStart and OnStop. Please see my code below.

Any idea what could be causing this?

```
public partial class BetGamesFeedService : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer _gamesTimer;
        private Timer _nextDrawTimer;
        private Timer _drawResultsTimer;
        private Timer _plannedScheduleTimer;

        private static readonly log4net.ILog log =
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public BetGamesFeedService()
        {
            try
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

                //Games Timer
                _gamesTimer = new Timer(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GamesInterval"]));
                _gamesTimer.Elapsed += GamesTimerOnElapsed;
                _gamesTimer.Enabled = true;

                //Next Draw Timer
                _nextDrawTimer = new Timer(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NextDrawInterval"]));
                _nextDrawTimer.Elapsed += NextDrawTimerOnElapsed;
                _nextDrawTimer.Enabled = true;

                //Draw Results Timer
                _drawResultsTimer = new Timer(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DrawResultsInterval"]));
                _drawResultsTimer.Elapsed += DrawResultsTimerOnElapsed;
                _drawResultsTimer.Enabled = true;

                //Planned Schedule Timer
                _plannedScheduleTimer = new Timer(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PlannedScheduleInterval"]));
                _plannedScheduleTimer.Elapsed += PlannedScheduleTimerOnElapsed;
                _plannedScheduleTimer.Enabled = true;

                InitializeComponent();

#if DEBUG
                OnStart(null);
#endif
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                _gamesTimer.Start();
                _nextDrawTimer.Start();
                _drawResultsTimer.Start();
                _plannedScheduleTimer.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                _gamesTimer.Stop();
                _nextDrawTimer.Stop();
                _drawResultsTimer.Stop();
                _plannedScheduleTimer.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        private async void GamesTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                var GamesOn = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GamesIntervalOn"]);
                if (!GamesOn) return;

                var betGames = new Bl.WindowsService.BetGames();
                await betGames.GetGamesAndAddToDatabase();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private async void NextDrawTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                var betGames = new Bl.WindowsService.BetGames();
                await betGames.GetNextDrawAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky5);
                await betGames.GetNextDrawAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky7);
                await betGames.GetNextDrawAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky6);
                await betGames.GetNextDrawAndAddToDatabase(Game.WheelOfFortune);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private async void DrawResultsTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                var betGames = new Bl.WindowsService.BetGames();
                await betGames.GetDrawResultsAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky5);
                await betGames.GetDrawResultsAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky7);
                await betGames.GetDrawResultsAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky6);
                await betGames.GetDrawResultsAndAddToDatabase(Game.WheelOfFortune);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private async void PlannedScheduleTimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                var betGames = new Bl.WindowsService.BetGames();
                await betGames.GetScheduledDrawsAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky5);
                await betGames.GetScheduledDrawsAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky7);
                await betGames.GetScheduledDrawsAndAddToDatabase(Game.Lucky6);
                await betGames.GetScheduledDrawsAndAddToDatabase(Game.WheelOfFortune);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class BetGames
    {
        private readonly int _partnerId =
            Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PartnerId"]);

        private readonly string _secretKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"];
        private readonly int _shopId = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShopId"]);

        private readonly string[] _method =
        {
            "get_screen_urls", "get_games", "ticket_buy", "ticket_check",
            "ticket_payout", "ticket_return"
        };

        private const string Language = "en";
        private const string Currency = "eur";

        private static readonly log4net.ILog log =
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public async Task GetGamesAndAddToDatabase()
        {
            try
            {
                const int methodIndex = 1;
                var request = new GetGamesRequest
                {
                    partner_id = _partnerId,
                    method = _method[methodIndex],
                    language = Language,
                    timestamp = GetTimestamp(),
                    @params = new BaseParams
                    {
                        currency = Currency,
                        shop_id = _shopId
                    }
                };
                request.signature = GetSignature(methodIndex, request.timestamp, request.@params);

                var api = new BetGamesAPI();
                var response = await api.GetGames(request);

                if (response == null)
                {
                    log.Info("GetGamesAndAddToDatabase(): No Data Returned.");
                    return;
                }

                if (response.response_code != 200)
                {
                    throw new Exception("response.response_code does not indicate success." + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Response Code: " + response.response_code + Environment.NewLine +
                                        "Response Error: " + response.error_message);
                }

                var games =
                    new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response.response.ToString(), typeof(List<Bo.Models.Game>))
                        as List<Bo.Models.Game>;

                //Add data to database
                foreach (var game in games)
                {
                    //@Id
                    var pId = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    pId.Value = game.id;

                    //@Name
                    var pName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    pName.Value = game.name;

                    //@Type
                    var pType = new SqlParameter("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    pType.Value = game.type;

                    //@Items
                    var dtItems = new DataTable();
                    dtItems.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
                    dtItems.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
                    dtItems.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));

                    foreach (var item in game.items)
                    {
                        dtItems.Rows.Add(item.id, item.number, item.color);
                    }

                    var pItems = new SqlParameter("@Items", SqlDbType.Structured);
                    pItems.Value = dtItems;
                    pItems.TypeName = "bg.ttItem";

                    //@Odds
                    var dtOdds = new DataTable();
                    dtOdds.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
                    dtOdds.Columns.Add("ItemsCount", typeof(int));
                    dtOdds.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                    dtOdds.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));

                    foreach (var odd in game.odds)
                    {
                        dtOdds.Rows.Add(odd.code, odd.items_count, odd.name, odd.value);
                    }

                    var pOdds = new SqlParameter("@Odds", SqlDbType.Structured);
                    pOdds.Value = dtOdds;
                    pOdds.TypeName = "bg.ttOdd";

                    using (var db = new BetGamesEntities())
                    {
                        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandText = "bg.InsertGameOddsAndItems";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pId);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pName);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pType);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pItems);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(pOdds);

                        db.Database.Connection.Open();
                        await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                        db.Database.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private string GetSignature(int methodIndex, int timestamp, object _params)
        {
            var jsonEncodedObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_params);
            var signatureBase = _partnerId + _method[methodIndex] + Language + timestamp + jsonEncodedObject;

            //Perform hashing
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_secretKey)))
            {
                var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureBase));
                return string.Concat(hash.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
            }
        }

        private static int GetTimestamp()
        {
            return (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        }

        public async Task GetNextDrawAndAddToDatabase(Game game)
        {
            try
            {
                var api = new BetGamesAPI();
                var response = await api.GetNextDraw(game);
                if (response == null)
                {
                    log.Info("GetNextDrawAndAddToDatabase(" + game + "): No data returned. Draw Probably currently running.");
                    return;
                }

                var data =
                    new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response.draws.ToString(), typeof(List<Bo.Models.Draw>)) as List<Bo.Models.Draw>;
                using (var db = new BetGamesEntities())
                {
                    db.InsertOrUpdateDraw(data[0].code, data[0].time.AddHours(2), Convert.ToBoolean(data[0].is_returned),
                        data[0].video_url);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public async Task GetDrawResultsAndAddToDatabase(Game game)
        {
            try
            {
                var api = new BetGamesAPI();
                using (var db = new BetGamesEntities())
                {
                    var drawCode = db.GetDrawCode((int)game).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (drawCode == null) return;

                    var response = await api.GetDraws(game, drawCode.Value);
                    if (response == null)
                    {
                        log.Info("GetDrawResultsAndAddToDatabase(" + game + "): No Data Returned");
                        return;
                    }

                    //Insert Data 
                    var data =
                        new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response.draws.ToString(), typeof(List<Bo.Models.Draw>)) as
                            List<Bo.Models.Draw>;

                    foreach (var draw in data)
                    {
                        //If this draw is Cancelled update the draw status to cancelled
                        if (draw.is_returned == 1)
                        {
                            db.InsertOrUpdateDraw(data[0].code, data[0].time.AddHours(2), Convert.ToBoolean(data[0].is_returned),
                                data[0].video_url);
                        }

                        //if we have results for this draw  
                        if (draw.results_entered == 1)
                        {
                            //@DrawCode
                            var pDrawCode = new SqlParameter("@DrawCode", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = draw.code };

                            //@Results
                            var dtResults = new DataTable();
                            dtResults.Columns.Add("BallNumber");
                            dtResults.Columns.Add("BallColor");

                            foreach (var result in draw.results)
                            {
                                dtResults.Rows.Add(result.Number, result.Color);
                            }

                            var pResults = new SqlParameter("@Results", SqlDbType.Structured)
                            {
                                Value = dtResults,
                                TypeName = "bg.ttDrawResult"
                            };

                            var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                            cmd.CommandText = "bg.InsertDrawResults";
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDrawCode);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(pResults);

                            db.Database.Connection.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            db.Database.Connection.Close();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public async Task GetScheduledDrawsAndAddToDatabase(Game game)
        {
            try
            {
                var api = new BetGamesAPI();
                var response = await api.GetScheduledDraws(game);
                if (response == null)
                {
                    log.Info("GetScheduledDrawsAndAddToDatabase(" + game + "): No data returned. Draw Probably currently running.");
                    return;
                }

                var data =
                    new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(response, typeof(List<Bo.Models.ScheduledDraw>)) as List<Bo.Models.ScheduledDraw>;
                using (var db = new BetGamesEntities())
                {

                    var scheduledDrawTable = new DataTable();
                    scheduledDrawTable.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(long));
                    scheduledDrawTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));

                    foreach (var draw in data)
                    {
                        scheduledDrawTable.Rows.Add(draw.number, draw.time.AddHours(2));
                    }

                    var Draws = new SqlParameter("@Draws", SqlDbType.Structured);
                    Draws.Value = scheduledDrawTable;
                    Draws.TypeName = "bg.ttDraw";

                    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "bg.InsertOrUpdateScheduledDraws";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(Draws);

                    db.Database.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    db.Database.Connection.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Anything in the windows event log that might help?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that there's nothing in the event logs

Comment: Well, in this case the only thing you can do is add a whole bunch of logging to narrow down the error. At this point it could be anything from broken API calls/responses to SQL server hiccups.

Comment: If you look at the code you will notice that i have try catches everywhere so i don't think i missed any out. Regardless of the many try catches, i still don't get any errors logged.